# Are custom labels in sandboxes automatically altered if they contain an organization id?

Tags: sandbox, customlabel, organization

We have a custom label that contains the organization id of our production org, to help regression/acceptance testing in sandboxes. Typically, the label is compared to the org id to determine to which address an e-mail should be sent.

Today I noticed that an e-mail, sent from a sandbox, was sent to the wrong address (i.e. the one associated with production). I noticed that the custom label contained the organization id of the sandbox, not that of production.

I checked in another sandbox: same thing, the custom label contains the organization id of the sandbox, not that of production.

The creation and modification times of the custom labels are exactly the same, on production and on the sandboxes: they all have one and the same creation and modification time! So it is not as if someone has changed this after sandbox creation/refresh.

I cannot find documentation that explains this. Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: Summary: yes, Salesforce automatically patches the ID from the origin org to the new org on copy, including text areas and metadata. Here's the link (now also in the original answer): https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_servers_and_ids.htm&type=5